# Passports for non-citizens

Tags: passport, non-citizens

Non-citizens have been getting Ethiopian passorts, although illegally.  What countries (if any) **legally** offer passports to resident non-citizens?  I'm looking for *any* requirement (or none) *other than citizenship*.  Passports for stateless persons or refugees would qualify, but I’m more interested in more common categories of residency.

Tried a web search, but all the hits were “how to get citizenship.”

Comment: A **non-citizen national of the United States** can get a US passport, but why do you assume that a  legal resident of USA (who is not a US citizen or national) can get one?

Comment: Legal resident vs. national.  Is the difference relevant to the actual question?

Comment: Since [Citizenship Evidence](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/how-apply/citizenship-evidence.html) is required to apply for a US passport: yes. A *non-citizen national of the United States* also recieves a different type of passport than US citizens. [Certificates of Non Citizen Nationality](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/legal/travel-legal-considerations/us-citizenship/Certificates-Non-Citizen-Nationality.html#:~:text=If%20a%20person%20believes%20he,facility%20in%20the%20United%20States.)

Comment: Different type; still a passport.  But I already know about USA—the question is other countries.  When I was hospitalero in Spain, I thought I had checked in folks with South African passports who weren't citizens there.  But either I was wrong, or the rules have changed, because South Africa is not doing that now.

Comment: The term you are looking for is **alien passport**.  Countries will, in most cases, only issue one when the person cannot get (or is very difficult to get) a national passport from their country. [Travel document - Reissue - Services - Service Berlin - Berlin.de](https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/325471/en/)

Comment: It is very likly that South Africa issued Zimbabwians alien passports for a certian period of time.

Comment: The German link starts out mentioning non-residents.  I'm interested in residents and/or nationals of the issuing country.

Comment: No, it states **authority for non-residents** (i.e. Immigration office) and contains as part of the **Prerequisites** is *Main residence in Berlin*. Therefore you must be a resident to get an aliens passport.

Comment: For German citizens, you go to your local registry office (where they know who you are and your citizenship) and make a paperless application for a passport (takes 10 minutes). The hardest part is getting the appointment.

Comment: Again, the question is which countries give passports to NON-citizens.  This includes refugees, stateless, etc. but I was really more interested in expatriates living legally in the country.

Comment: @WGroleau the US doesn't do that, and afaik neither any other country in the world. US non-citizen nationals are residents of very specific places (Guam and northern Mariana islands, iirc), not expats from anywhere else

Comment: @littleadv, the group you have mentioned, non-citizen nationals, IS eligible for a US passport (Mark Johnson cited a state department page on that).  But I see that it is a smaller group than I had in mind.

Comment: @WGroleau yes, because they're us nationals, not because they're expats.

Comment: Indeed, expats _is_ what I had in mind, although it is not the word I used.

Comment: You should reformulate your question to make it clear that you mean citizens from **other** countries (for the US: Green Card holders etc. who do not owe a permanent allegiance to the US as US citizens and Nationals do - Section 101(a)(21) of the Immigration and Nationality Act).

Answer (score 3):

Passports are issued to nationals of a country. So any country that has a distinction between "nationals" and "citizens" will have non-citizen nationals getting passports. For example:

- There are 6 types of British national: British citizen, British Overseas Territories citizen (BOTC), British Overseas citizen (BOC), British National (Overseas) (BN(O)), British subject, and British protected person. All of these get British passports. Only one of them is called British "citizen", although some of the others have "citizen" in the name. Some of them (e.g. BN(O)) don't have "citizen" in the name.
- In some Latin American countries, for example Mexico, only people 18 or over can be considered "citizens" (ciudadanos). Children under 18 born in the country still get passports.

Many countries issue passport-like travel documents to people who are not nationals in some circumstances. These are variously called things like [refugee travel document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refugee_travel_document), [1954 convention travel document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1954_Convention_travel_document), [certificate of identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_of_identity), [re-entry permit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Re-entry_permit), etc., but they don't usually have "passport" in the name.

Latvia, Lithuania, and Estonia issue "[alien's passports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estonian_alien%27s_passport)" to their "[non-citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-citizens_(Latvia))" or people with "[undefined citizenship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estonian_nationality_law#Undefined_citizenship)", a special class of people in those countries.

Another interesting case is the Holy See, which issues [Holy See service passports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vatican_and_Holy_See_passports) to people in its diplomatic service, including some who are Vatican City citizens, and some who are not Vatican City citizens.

Comment: This is helpful.  But perhaps I must examine each country specifically to get a full answer.